# Jmeter Server with modified execute(allowed) permission still not executable

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do a distributed testing to JSON APIs. But in Ubuntu 14.04, Jmeter-server (the slaves) just don't run. I have tried chmod +x, going root, even the hazards of chmod 777. But still, when you execute "./jmeter-server", permission denied still appears. Why is this so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you also `chmod +x` on the `/bin/jmeter` file.

`/bin/jmeter-server` in turn calls `/jmeter` to start.

Comment: Yeah I just checked by removing executable from my jmeter file on my load generator:
[root@jmeter_lg_20 bin]# chmod -x jmeter
[root@jmeter_lg_20 bin]# ./jmeter-server
./jmeter-server: line 32: ./jmeter: Permission denied